# Keybindings not working - swing

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have been trying to make a small program that prints messages when the user presses a key, however it doesn't print the message. The following is my code:

```
    public static void key() {
    Main main = new Main();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JComponent component = frame.getRootPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(main);
    System.out.println("adad");

    Action test = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("w has been pressed");
        }
    };
    component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0),"test");
    component.getActionMap().put("test", test);

}
```

There are no errors but when the "w" key is pressed actionPerformed isn't called. What am I doing wrong? I don't know if this is relevant, but here is the main method, maybe i'm doing something wrong here.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main main = new Main();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(main);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    key();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(frame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a second frame which is not visible on the screen, which the key bindings are bound too...

As I said yesterday, the key bindings must be registered with a component which is attached to a displayable component (one which is attached to a native peer) before they will work

If you try using something more like...

```
public static void key(JComponent component) {
    Action test = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("w has been pressed");
        }
    };
    component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "test");
    component.getActionMap().put("test", test);

}
```

and pass either the instance of `JFrame` or one of it's child components (like `main` or the `contentPane`) from your `public static void main(...)` method, it should work

Comment: Finally! Thanks for the help. Works fine now

Comment: @Ky6000 Now you understand the importance of a  [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. It will result in less confusion and better responses. The code I remember seeing yesterday didn't identify the source of the `JComponent`. The more context you can provide, the better we can diganose your issues